# Update screen with reducer in react native

Tags: react-native, redux, reducers, redux-reducers

im trying to add a picture in the task, and after this, update the flatlist to see the update but it does not with. It works if I close and return on the app.
If I display the store, I also see an instant update but not in my screen.

Here is a part of my code :

TaskImage.js

```
    openImageLibrary=async(task)=>{
      const result = await ImageHelpers.openImageLibrary();
      if(result){
        const downloadUrl=await this.uploadImage(result,task)
        this.props.UpdateTaskImage({...task,uri:downloadUrl})
      }
    }


....
const mapStateToProps=state=>{
    return{
      tasks:state.tasks
    };
  }
  
  const mapDispatchToProps=dispatch=>{
    return{
      loadTasks:tasks=> dispatch({type:'LOAD_TASKS_FROM_SERVER',payload:tasks}),
      addTask:task=>dispatch({type:'ADD_TASK',payload:task}),
      DeleteTask: task=>dispatch({type:'DELETE_TASK',payload:task}),
      UpdateTaskImage:task=>dispatch({type:'UPDATE_TASK_IMAGE',payload:task}) 
    }
  }
```

TasksReducer.js :

```
const initialState={
    tasks:[],
    image:null
}

const tasks=(state=initialState,action)=>{
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case 'LOAD_TASKS_FROM_SERVER':
            return{
                ...state,
                tasks:action.payload
            };
    case 'UPDATE_TASK_IMAGE':
        return{
            ...state,
            tasks:state.tasks.map(task=>{
            if(task.task==action.payload.task)
            {
                return {...task,image:action.payload.uri}
            }
            return task
            })
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default tasks;
```

Any idea..?

Comment: Are you copying the `tasks` prop into component state somewhere?  That would be a cause of delayed updates.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see more of your code, but here's what I think I'm seeing. How are the Flatlist items updated after the redux update? What I think may be your problem is that the Flatlist props are not also mapped to the redux state or directly passed down from this component's `tasks` prop. The Flatlist will re-render when its `data` prop is changed, so ensure that is the case.

Other than this consideration, ensure that in any case you're using redux correctly. I think you may be missing the call to the `connect` function. See the [redux official doc](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#connect-extracting-data-with-mapstatetoprops), which uses this example:

```
// TodoList.js

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { todos } = state
  return { todoList: todos.allIds }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoList)
```

Comment: Okay.. do you have an example please?